# Regular expression for ensuring domain name is English characters only

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, string

What's a good, clear regex for matching a domain name that must consist of:

- Only English alpha characters, plus numbers
- Including spaces or other separator characters that are valid, and reliably handled within a domain name

To clarify, this is for the purposes of validating a domain name.  Whilst there are moves in the internet community to support internationalisation of domain names, I've done a fair bit of research into this and to keep my explanation fairly simple, only domain names that include characters that are part of a modern UK English character set (including numbers) are reliably handled by the Domain Name System (DNS).  I'm not indicating a desire to prohibit internationalisation - I've done a lot of work during my career doing the opposite!

---

To answer this, what I was looking for is something like this (tested and works).  Sorry the original question wasn't explicit enough about what I was trying to do, however I've upvoted the suggestions that have helped me provide this answer to the commmunity:

^[\w- .]*$

- '\w' = shorthand for [a-zA-Z0-9_]
- '- .' = allow '-', ' ', '.'
- asterisk = any of the previous characters zero or more times

Comment: The `\w` special character is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `\s` is shorthand for an empty character (space, tab etc). Bad news is, "other separator characters" need to be listed explicitly because it can not know what you exactly mean by separator since an accent itself could well be one such as in `123´abc`.

Comment: Speaking English, the most common separator is comma. What "other separators" you want to match? Any punctuation characters?

Comment: What are "English alpha characters"? Is "Coöperate" English? I cannot believe this got 4 upvotes...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one:

```
(?i)[a-z0-9\p{Z}]
```

where `\p{Z}` is "All separators" class and `i` ignore-case option.

Comment: You get a +1 from me for the correct answer... but I just want to mention here, that I've been scolded before for encouraging questions like this by answering them ;)

Comment: @m.buettner, That's right. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @m.buettner :: Is that what OP has asked for? I don't think so! `\p{Z}` represents any kind of **whitespace or invisible separator** (http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: @Ωmega, Currently we don't know what OP wants...

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow, In this case specify all separator characters instead of `p{Z}`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `[a-zA-Z\d\s\p{P}]+` as the most simple solution. Or go with non-unicode solution >>

POSIX defines character classes `[:...:]` , but not every regex engine support them.

But alternative sets can be used then...

```
[:alnum:]   [A-Za-z0-9]                            Alphanumeric characters
[:space:]   [ \t\r\n\v\f]                          Whitespace   characters
[:punct:]   [\]\[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]   Punctuation  characters
```

So putting them together you will get

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 \t\r\n\v\f\]\[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+$
```

This way you see what you going to match and what not. Please note that some characters are escaped by `\` as without escaping they would have different meaning.